# Settup form script for ajax and post calls

Tags: php, ajax, session

i would like to know if its possible to set up my script so it can be handled by http ajax call and alternatively also the classic post way:

on the top i am first doing this:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){
    $AnswerType = 'die';
}
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
    $AnswerType = 'session';
}
```

Then i check if either of these two is set by doing the following:

```
if ($AnswerType == 'die' || $AnswerType == 'session' ){
*here i run my script*
}
```

When the script ends i finally try to send all responses in my $respond_message array back the way the form where initialy posted:

```
if ($AnswerType = 'die'){
        die(print_r($respond_message));
    }
    if ($AnswerType = 'session'){
        $_SESSION['formrespondmessage'].= print_r($respond_message);
        header("Location: /");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the script to react different on ajax and on simple post request? I think in this case the best solution is just to pass any variable, which indicates, that data is being sent by ajax. Like this:

postparams['ajax']=1;
$.post(...

And then in php make check like this:

if (isset($_POST['ajax'])) {
  code for ajax request
} else {
  code for simple post request
}

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your code, I prefer not to use so complicated scripts, at least you need to add () after serializeArray, possibly everything else looks ok. I would do like this:

```
<form name="form1" id="form1">
<input type="text" name="qq" value="ww">
</form>
<input type="button" onclick="dt=$('#form1').serializeArray();dt[dt.length]={name: 'ajax', 'value': 1};$.post('test.php', dt, function(data) {alert(data)});">
```

And in php file just check if isset($_POST["ajax"]). For example, my looks like this:

```
<?
if (isset($_POST["ajax"])) print_r($_POST);
?>
```